# isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) returns true even when no internt is enabled

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am checking for active internet connection in a google maps app , and i want to do a specific action when the internet is active and another if the internet is inactive.

```
if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        {
            getcurrentlocation();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Internet is mandatory for this application,\n connect and restart the app")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
```

The problem is that the manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) returns true even when no internet is present.Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

isproviderenabled returns string of currently enabled provider.It doesn't give the status of active network connection.Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String))

If you want to check if device has internet connection,call following function.
Check for its value and if it's null alert user else do your stuff

```
public boolean isconnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Change your if conditon to as follows

```
 if(isconnected())
   getcurrentlocation();
 else
   //alert user
```

Comment: isProviderEnabled return Boolean value